# PyCharm is not Launching on Windows! What's wrong with it?

Tags: python, pycharm

I downloaded and installed JetBrains PyCharm (Community version) on my Windows 10, but nothing happens when I try to run it. I tried everything like rebooting Windows, Run as administrator, etc. Nothing is found in Task Manager either.

Comment: missing or old java version on your machine? java -version?

Comment: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13) 
Checking from browser: Your system is managed by your organization IT department. The following Java versions were detected on your system. 
 Java 8 Update 101 (static)
 Java 8 Update 101 (64-bit)

Comment: Can you check for any error information in the logs, they should be here `<DRIVE>\Users\<username>\.Pycharm<version>`

Comment: I have tried pycharm.exe and it will never run and never display any message. Just found pycharm64.exe under the same folder and it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shortcut pointed to pycharm.exe which will never work no matter how you invoke it for some reason. Maybe my Windows doesn't have a 32 bit java version.

I found **pycharm64.exe** under the same folder by chance, and that one works.

It would be nice if the installer can figure out what version should be running, or at least someone puts a reminder on the download page.

Comment: I did a bit a digging.  The shortcut my system is using points directly to that pycharm64.exe, and yet the shortcut doesn't work and opening the *.exe as you said does.
I don't know windows well enough to debug that.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have Java installed on your windows 10.

Comment: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)

Answer (score 2):

I recently faced this problem. I am using Pycharm (2020.1). I am going to show you how it worked for me.

Solution:
Press `window` key and search for pycharm.

[image]

Do not click on Pycharm Community Edition.
Simply click on the batch file given below (pycharm)
[image]

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem many times, the launcher window will open and then immediately close without any error message. In my case it seems that this happens when I have insufficient disk space. Clearing 10-15Gb solves it for me. Hope that helps.