# PyCharm doesnt startup after installation. Tried reinstalling it but nothing works. Why?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have an installation issue. I have tried reinstalling the IDE, deleted all directories but nothing worked.

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error? If so, paste the error here with your question. Are you able to run it from your terminal (perhaps with a verbose flag to display a trace of what's happening)?

Comment: No the ide is not opening at all. As soon as I double click on the ide the cursor loads and nothing happens. There is a file named Portlock in the following directory.

C:\Users\Bhaskar\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2020.1

Is that file usual to have?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm unfamiliar with that file in windows. You could perhaps take a look at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207745045-PyCharm-not-opening-on-Windows-10 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231450/pycharm-is-not-launching-on-windows-whats-wrong-with-it

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for the above-mentioned problem. If u ever face launching issues with pycharm.

Reinstall it. Change the **default installation Directory** at the time of installation.
You are good to go.

Eg: The default installation directory will look like this : **C:\Program Files\PyCharm 2020.1**

Add a new folder named XYZ in the **Program Files** directory. In my case I created a folder named **"PyCharm"**

My new installation directory is now: **C:\Program Files\PyCharm\PyCharm 2020.1**